# I define a void pointer myPoint in Objective-c global eare by: static void *myPoint = myPoint;

Tags: objective-c, void

define a void pointer myPoint in Objective-c global eare by: 
static void *myPoint = myPoint;
what is this actually mean?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on StackOverflow (after a significant improvement).

Answer (score 1):

It means you are totally confused. I would not expect this to compile on Objective-C. In C++ it might compile but would be more than pointless.

As a rule, if you see a slightly complicated expression or statement, look at it bit by bit. You should know what static means. You should know what void* means. You should know what static void* myPoint means. You should know what static void* myPoint = NULL means. And then it should be obvious what static void* myPoint = myPoint would mean if it was legal.

Comment: What your answer says is that read the answer once again and read this comment again until you feel sleepy :D